# Method error, not pulling GPS coordinates for users

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, geolocation, coordinates

I'm trying to set current GPS coordinates in my user create method.  It's not working. I've done this before with a previous project and it worked. What exactly am I missing?

I'm extracting the location from the browser through getLocation()

[image]

Turning it into a cookie through javascript. ( I tested the cookie alone , it IS successfully capturing the coordinates as a cookie.

[image]

defining the method through application_controller.rb

[image]

calling the method in the create method in user_controller.rb

[image]

latitude and longitude are in my schema

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what's going on is that Ruby runs first before the JavaScript, and even though you collected the location, it is not pushed to Ruby. I would consider using AJAX.